# TouchableOpacity onpress is not working with Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, touchableopacity, react-native-paper

I am using react native Navigation and I put a switch inside the header to toggle between light and dark theme while using touchableOpacity onPress prop. No error logs, and when I press the switch, the touchableOpacity onpress is not firing up. I did share my App.js code, I would appreciate if you can see and point where I am doing wrong.

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */

import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {StatusBar, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import Home from './src/screens/Home';
import Details from './src/screens/Details';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {DarkTheme, Text, Title, TouchableRipple, Switch} from 'react-native-paper';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();


const App = () => {

  const [isDartheme, setDarkTheme] = useState(false);

  const togglemethod = () => {
      console.log("Called!");
    setDarkTheme(!isDartheme);
  };


  return (
    <>

          
      <NavigationContainer>
        <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerTitleAlign: 'center'}}>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={Home}
            options={{
              headerTitle: (props) => (
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <View>
                  <Title style={{paddingLeft: 130}}>
                    <Text>Home</Text>
                  </Title>
                </View>
          
                
                  <View >
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={ () => {togglemethod() }
                      }
                      centered ={true}
                      >
                          <MaterialCommunityIcons
                        name={isDartheme?'moon-waning-crescent': 'white-balance-sunny'}
                        size = {25}
                        color= "blue"
                        style={{paddingLeft: 110, paddingBottom:5, width: '200%'}}
                        > 
                      <Switch
                        value={isDartheme}
                        color="red"
                        style={{paddingLeft: 8}}
                      />
                      </MaterialCommunityIcons>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                </View>
                  
              ),
            }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </> 
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: import TouchableOpacity from react-native instead of react-native-gesture-handler

Comment: the issue still persists.

Comment: I have even edited the question. just others not assume as you. I am still having trouble to solve this issue.

Comment: But what are you effectively clicking, the switch? You should handle it within the switch then, by the method `onValueChange`, can you please try it? Or try removing the switch and see if it's working.

Comment: Yes modified to like this ```onValueChange = {() => console.log("pressed!")}``` just to see "pressed!" output in the console but nothing outputted. now I am thinking more that the issue is in the stack. please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo on the method that you are calling change the onPress from `togglemlethod` to `togglemethod`

Comment: I am still facing the issue, yeah it is true there was a typo. I corrected and still not firing up. did you try to run it on your own?

Comment: I have even edited the question. just others not to assume as you. I am still having trouble to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working version of the code,

1. You should not place the Switch inside the icon which results in an error
2. You can use the switch itself to trigger the toggle,

You will have to change the styles according to your need, but this works fine on android.

```
 <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerTitleAlign: 'center' }}>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{
            headerTitle: (props) => (
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <View>
                  <Title style={{ paddingLeft: 130 }}>
                    <Text>Home</Text>
                  </Title>
                </View>

                <View>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                      togglemethod();
                    }}
                    centered={true}
                    style={{ flexDirection: 'row',alignItems:'center' }}>
                    <Switch
                      value={isDartheme}
                      color="red"
                      onValueChange={() => togglemethod()}
                    />
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons
                      name={
                        isDartheme
                          ? 'moon-waning-crescent'
                          : 'white-balance-sunny'
                      }
                      size={25}
                      color="blue"
                      style={{
                        paddingBottom: 5,
                      }}></MaterialCommunityIcons>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </View>
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: i tested this on Android and it worked fine, are you having any other wrappers that you have not mentioned here ?

Comment: the component ```component={Home}``` contains code doing some search. but how it could affect the switch I didn't understand.

Comment: Here is the Home component code https://pastebin.com/jCw6avhW

Comment: Not the home component your navigator or App.js

Comment: I pasted it here [https://pastebin.com/F6gvASxZ ] take a look

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/nervous-orange, see it works

Comment: it is showing an error! **unable to resolve Module @react-navigation/native.js**

Comment: Maybe some cache issue, refresh and try again maybe? because i can see the output

Comment: I add all the codes needed and still having some issue take a look plz https://snack.expo.io/_9wxOUnJW

Comment: yours is working, I saw it but when added some more codes like search.js it is not working I dont know what the issue is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218340/discussion-between-hanan-and-guruparan-giritharan).